# How do i print page number in @media print?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to show page numbers while printing. I am able to get page numbers using counter but i cant figure out a way to show it in any proper way in every page.

I followed this. but its not working. Checked on Firefox and Chrome.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page

```
@page {

    @top-right {
        counter-increment: page;
        content: counter(page);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this
make sure you update your browser first then write the below code
although this is for footer but you can adjust it to works for top right too

```
 @content {
 display: table;
 }

 @pageFooter {
 display: table-footer-group;
 }

 @pageFooter:after {
 counter-increment: page;
 content: counter(page);
 }
```

you may create class for top right as below

```
 @topright {
 position: absolute;
 top: 8px;
 right: 16px;
 font-size: 18px;
 }
```

good luck